# Android How to LinearLayout (or other views) set clickable and focusable

Tags: java, android, focusable

[image: Like this]

I want to set focusable and clickable mode for LinearLayout (like in above image). How to I make this?

Comment: try this myBtn.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

Comment: if you have need more then i will post here grt answer for custom all the things like theame

Comment: Thats code isn't work

Comment: look at this link http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/changing-background-color-and-border-color-of-an-edittext-widget-using-state-list-in-android/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, it worked for me

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:clickable="true"
              android:focusable="true"
              android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the XML file that you defined, you can have in your element:

android:focusable="true"

or

android:clickable="true"